# Handsontable: Adding drop down values dynamically

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am adding a drop down to all columns of the first row using the following code.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container,
    {
        data: results,
        colWidths: [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
        colHeaders: false,
        contextMenu: true,
        cells : function (row, col, prop) {
            if (row === 0) {
              this.type = 'dropdown';
              var val = this.instance.getValue();
              if(typeof val != 'undefined') {
                this.source = [val, 'Code', 'Type', 'Color'];
              }
            }
        }
    });
```

In my cells function I am trying to add the current cell value to the drop down (default values are Code, Type and Color). But if the user decided to enter in "Weight" in the cell, then I would want the drop down to contain ("Weight", "Code", "Type" and "Color").

The function above did do this but not correctly... The value that was added got replaced by the next every time the function was called.

I then tried creating a list which I would add the value `val` to and setting `source` to that list.

But I can't help but feeling that there is a better way to do this.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I've dealt extensively with dynamically adding values to dropdowns. Can you explain a little better what you mean by the function not working correctly? What it's doing is replacing the source (of every cell row===0) each time you make a change to any cell with the current value on each cell plus those others. What do you want to happen exactly?

Comment: Here's an example of the behavior. We start with the following values in the drop down ("Code", "Type" and "Color"). The user then decides to change the cell value of "Code" to "Weight", at this point the drop down reads ("Weight", "Code", "Type" and "Color". Now if the user decides to change "Weight" for "Height", the drop down would then read ("Height", "Code", "Type" and "Color"). But I would like it to read ("Height", "Weight", "Code", "Type" and "Color"). In short I want all the values ever entered in the first row to be in the drop down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, from what your comment says, you seem to want to APPEND values to your source list. Therefore, I would suggest the following:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container,
    {
    data: results,
    colWidths: [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
    colHeaders: false,
    contextMenu: true,
    cells : function (row, col, prop) {
        if (row === 0) {
          this.type = 'dropdown';
          var val = this.instance.getValue();
          if(typeof val != 'undefined') {
            this.source.push(val); // to add to the beginning do this.source.unshift(val) instead
          }
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is append the current value to the source list. This way, the next time you enter a value, it will get appended rather than replaced.

Comment: Is there a way to add change data of dropdown on change of any other dropdown ? I am tring afterChange callback, but have not succeeded yet

Comment: Could you maybe post a question with a more detailed explanation? You CAN do you what you're suggesting but the specifics may be tricky

Answer (score -6):

```
<select ng-repeat="myModel">
 <option value=1>First Selection</option>
 <option value=2>Second Selection</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Consider explaining what your code does and how it answers the question.